# How to set datepicker locale with Struts2 jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, struts2

How can I set a different locale to my `<sj:datepicker>`?

I use the Struts2 jQuery plugin bundled with MyEclipse 8.5, and I found some different locales, but I can't set it!

Answer (score 2):

you can set the jQuery locale in the [Head Tag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag).

```
<sj:head locale="de" ... />
```